# Pygame-OpenGL cannot fill the surface

Tags: python, opengl

I have started to code a person body with Python - OpenGL to learn the library, however when I use `glColor3fv((1.000, 0.498, 0.314))` it only fills the part of the surface and not the all surface.

All my imports:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
```

I have made a class here:

```
class body():
    def __init__(self):
        self.vertices = (
        (0.05, -0.15, -0.25),
        (0.05, 0.05, -0.25),
        (0.05, 0.15, -0.15),
        (0.05, 0.15, 0.15),
        (0.05, 0.05, 0.25),
        (0.05, -0.15, 0.25),
        (0.05, -0.25, 0.15),
        (0.05, -0.25, -0.15),
        (-0.05, -0.15, -0.25),
        (-0.05, 0.05, -0.25),
        (-0.05, 0.15, -0.15),
        (-0.05, 0.15, 0.15),
        (-0.05, 0.05, 0.25),
        (-0.05, -0.15, 0.25),
        (-0.05, -0.25, 0.15),
        (-0.05, -0.25, -0.15)
        )

        self.edges = (
            (0, 1),
            (0, 8),
            (1, 2),
            (1, 9),
            (2, 3),
            (2, 10),
            (3, 4),
            (3, 11),
            (4, 5),
            (4, 12),
            (5, 6),
            (5, 13),
            (6, 7),
            (6, 14),
            (7, 0),
            (7, 15),
            (8, 9),
            (9, 10),
            (10, 11),
            (11, 12),
            (12, 13),
            (13, 14),
            (14, 15),
            (15, 8),
            )

        self.surfaces = (
            (0, 1, 8, 9),
            (1, 2, 9, 10),
            (2, 3, 10, 11),
            (3, 4, 11, 12),
            (4, 5, 12, 13),
            (5, 6, 13, 14),
            (6, 7, 14, 15),
            (7, 0, 15, 8),
            (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7),
            (8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15)
            )
```

My class has only one function for now:

```
def create_part(self):
    glBegin(GL_LINES)
    for edge in self.edges:
        for vertex in edge:
            glVertex3fv(self.vertices[vertex])
    glEnd()

    glBegin(GL_QUADS)
    for surface in self.surfaces:
        for vertex in surface:
            glColor3fv((1.000, 0.498, 0.314))
            glVertex3fv(self.vertices[vertex])
    glEnd()
```

Finally to see the object in screen I have:

```
""" TEST"""
x_object = body().create_part
def main():
    pygame.init()
    display = (800, 600)

    pygame.display.set_mode(display, DOUBLEBUF|OPENGL)

    gluPerspective(45, (display[0]/display[1]), 0.1, 50.0)
    glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, -5)

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        glRotatef(1, 10, 3, 1)

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
        x_object()
        pygame.display.flip()
        pygame.time.wait(10)

main()
```

but when I run my codes it looks:[image: code sample]

problem should be at `create_part()` function but I could not understand why

Comment: "only fills the part of the surface and not the all surface" could you please specify what exactly you meant by this.

Comment: @SimonKirsten as you can see from the picture(picture only show the front side of the object) my function only fill the right side and left side but not filling the middle side of it.

Comment: Could you please provide all the vertices as some are missing.

Comment: On a side note: `glColor3fv` is a function that changes a state in OpenGl. In this case it changes the colour OpenGl uses to draw things. That means you should not do this every time you draw something. Only call this function if you want to change the colour, as these state change functions are costly.

Comment: @SimonKirsten Sorry About that I add them

Comment: It seems like some indices are wrong. I cannot help you really because this would be a tedious task to check all the indices and vertices. Sorry, but i hope you will find the error.

Comment: @SimonKirsten Do you think it is about surfaces definition ? So that I can check my points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like some indices are wrong. I cannot help you really because this would be a tedious task to check all the indices and vertices.

[image]

As you can see point 3 is used for the green triangle, when indeed point 2 should be used.